# Firebase Authentication - Sign In With Google blocked in Firefox with Enhanced Tracking Protection

Tags: firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase SignInWithGoogle in my React project, but when the "Enhanced tracking protection" is enabled in Firefox, it doesn't work.
I can choose user, and complete the process without seeing any error, but the user is not logged in nor added to the user list in my Firebase console.

I'm using it via Context:

```
export const UserContextProvider = ({ children }) => {

      const googleSignIn = () => {
        const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
        signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
      };
return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ googleSignIn, createUser, user, logout, signIn }}>
      {!loading && children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Everything works well in other browsers, as well as in Firefox with the protection switched off.
Did anyone face a similar problem?